# How do I debug my Java source code that I am calling from the MATLAB environment?

Tags: java, eclipse, matlab, debugging

Based on the following link:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102080

In order to debug Java code being called from the MATLAB environment, use the following steps:

1. Relaunch MATLAB using the -jdb flag from a command prompt. For example:

   matlab -jdb

   (by default this flag will enable debugging support in the VM on port 4444)
2. You can either launch a Java debugger from a Java IDE such as Eclipse and Intellij, or call jdb from the system command prompt. MATLAB displays the message “JVM is being started with debugging enabled” and provides the appropriate information. For example:

   jdb -connect com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach:port=4444
3. After attaching the debugger you will be able to set breakpoints as you normally would.

Can anyone explains these steps more detail, especially for step 3? How to attach the debugger (Assuming I'm using eclipse).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

3) in details.

- Import your java project to eclipse (possible without, but easier this way)
- Configure your java-project to use the same JRE your matlab-version uses. Maybe you have to install it because Matlab has a bundled version (Not required to debug, but required to modify and recompile)
- Create a new launch configuration for debugging, set IP and Port.
- Run the configuration, to attach to an existing application.