# Debug Java in MATLAB - jdb is not found

Tags: java, matlab, debugging, jdb

I am trying to debug java application within matlab using the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142741).

Matlab starts good and echo:

> JVM is being started with debugging enabled.
>
> Use "jdb -connect com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach:port=4444" to attach debugger.

but when I try to attach the debugger I get:

> >> jdb -connect com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach:port=4444
>
> Undefined function 'jdb' for input arguments of type 'char'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ***jdb*** outside Matlab.

***jdb*** is is a standalone app that allows you to connect to running JVM.